# Gspread add value capabiliy

Tags: python-2.7, google-sheets-api, gspread

I am trying to make a raspberry pi add 1 each time a button is pressed to the same cell, but I have not found any way to do this. Does anyone have any recommendations?

Comment: Can you add any details like: code used, error problem encountered? [How do I ask a good question?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask), [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) Show the community what you have tried.

Comment: I am new to python and don't know how to code very well. I have looked through all the given code on this website and others such as the issue page on github but I have not found anything that would allow me to add a value every time a button is pressed. I am looking for something that could work like a function of n+1, n being the number recorded on the spreadsheet, whenever someone presses a button. Can anyone help me?